# Do email results come in the same order as the list of emails

Tags: apex, sobject, apex-email-service, singleemailmessage

I populate a list of emails `emailsToBeSent` and send them all at once. However These emails are related to different sObjects. And to me it is important to know which sObject the returned results are related to in the case of an error.

Here's the code I have right now:

```
Messaging.sendEmail(emailsToBeSent);
```

For that I get a list of results with a `isSuccess()` value. How can I know which result is related to what sObject?

My only hope is - perhaps if the returned list of results keeps the order of the emails from the `emailsToBeSent` list. Can anybody confirm or reject this idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer the specific question, the `sendEmail` method returns a list of `Messaging.SendEmailResult` objects. This list will be in the same order as the corresponding list of emails provided to sendEmail(..).

As Mohith pointed out, you can only discover whether the email message was successfully queued for delivery, and, if not, why. You can't discover if the email was actually sent, let alone received.

So, to correlate to the Sobjects in question, you can do either:

- Maintain a map of EmailMessage index position (within the list) to SObjectId or ..
- Iterate through the `Messaging.SendEmailResult` list as shown below

  ```
  for (Messaging.SendEmailResult ser: Messaging.sendEmails(emailList))
     if (!ser.isSuccess())
        // do something with ser.getErrors().getTargetObjectId()
  ```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! That's exactly what I was planning on!

Comment: a final tip -- emails are never sent in testmethods so don't expect to see any of them in your inbox

Answer (score 3):

First of all isSuccess=true does not mean the Email was sent .Carefully look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_sendemail_emailresult.htm)

> Even if success = true, it does not mean the intended recipients received the email, as it could have bounced or been blocked by a spam blocker. Also, even if the email is successfully accepted for delivery by the message transfer agent, there can still be errors in the error array related to individual addresses within the email.

So the best way to track this is via reports in SFDC

https://www.shellblack.com/administration/email-deliverabilty-and-html-status-reports/

Check [this](http://www.simplysfdc.com/2015/11/salesforce-email-status.html) article shows how as an admin you can enable Email Tracking and track the email in the related list .

Comment: Thanks for the response @MohithShrivastava. Always knowledgeable. However can you tell me how can I relate the results to a particular sObject? That's what is more important to my project at the moment. I need to be able to know which results are related to what sObject.

Comment: Use setTargetId() method and use setSaveAsActiviy() to create activity .

Comment: The results will show up in results for you out of box